# Error when trying to get into multiplayer

Tags: crysis-2

I cannot go into multiplayer mode in Crysis 2!

I recently bought Crysis 2 Maximum Edition on Steam.  I also registered at [Mycrisis](http://www.mycrysis.com/). But I cannot get into the multiplayer mode. I always get an error message to check my internet connection, while everything is fine with my internet connection. Can someone help me please?

**Edit:**
I get the error when clicking "Multiplayer" in main menu, not while joining a multiplayer game.

**Edit 2:** Crysis 2 from DVD works fine, Crysis 2 Maximum Edition from Steam doesn´t work.

Comment: I suspect router settings are to blame.  Do you have multiple computers on the network?  Know anything about port forwarding?

Comment: @fbueckert It´s not about a multiplayer GAME, it´s about getting into the multiplayer menu

Comment: Yes, you have now clarified.  We still need more information, though.  What's the exact error message?  Have you tried to Google that error message?

Comment: There is no "exact error message"; when i click on multiplayer a popup appears with the text: "You have to be connected to the internet for multiplayer. Please check your internet connection!"

Comment: Googling that error message brings up the suggestion to turn off your Windows Firewall.  Have you tried that?

Comment: My firewall is always completely deactivated

Comment: If you have no firewall, are you behind a router?  If so, it also has a firewall, and you need to figure out how to open the correct ports and forward them to the correct computer.

Comment: With my internet connection and firewall settings is everything fine... I´m a software engineer normally I´m good at this stuff, and I have to note: Crysis 2 from DVD works fine in multiplayer, Crysis 2 Maximum Edition from Steam doesn´t work.

Comment: I'm afraid that you may have to check out Crysis's forums in order to resolve the issue; I'm at the end of what tech support I can provide, and no one else seems to be having the same issue.